# Unable to update in EF, says "The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to update a column of a table using entity framework. The database has triggers involved as well. So when I try to do saveChanges(), it says {"The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted."}

I am not getting what this error means. Can any one in plain words explain me what this could mean. I don't expect complete answer but the overall view of the error will help. If someone can point out points in which I can work upon so that I can solve the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing the trigger rolled back the transaction (but didn't throw an error)

Comment: I guess you have worked out what it mean. You know that you can write answer to your question and get small points for it?